Get sign function only by common operations
I beg your tolerance and patience as I am not a mathematician.
May be that's why I have a question I am unable to solve for many year.
I wonder if it is possible to write a function only with common operator  (+,-,*,/), that is this function:
x=0   --> y=0
|x|>0 --> y=1

The simplest would be
y=x/x, but division by 0 is not allowed.
In Calc:
y=sign(abs(x)), but those are not common operators
I am afraid that even absolute value |x| cannot be expressed only by
operations  (+,-,*,/).
I guess it is somehow related with group and neutral and inverse member, or what it is called.
Anyway I would be happy for any (understandable) answer. :-)
Thank you in advance.

No, it's not possible. The functions you can describe with only those operations are all rational functions such as $\frac{1}{1 - x^2}$, and rational functions cannot behave this way (they also can't express either $\text{sign}$ or $\text{abs}$).
If $r(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} = 1$ for all $x \neq 0$, where $p, q$ are polynomials and we assume that the fraction is in lowest terms so $p$ and $q$ have no common factors, then $p(x) = q(x)$ for all $x \neq 0$. A general fact about polynomials is that if they agree at infinitely many points then they agree identically, so $p(x) = q(x)$ for all $x$, including at $x = 0$. Since $p$ and $q$ have no common factors they can't both be divisible by $x$, so the only possibility is that $p(0) = q(0) \neq 0$, which gives $r(0) = 1$.
More generally rational functions cannot have removable discontinuities; they are continuous everywhere except at a finite set of points called the poles at which they are infinite. This means $\text{sign}$ is not rational because it is not continuous at all, and rational functions are also differentiable everywhere except at their poles which also rules out $\text{abs}$.

Thank you for the affirmation, that it is impossible. :-) I spend many hours searching after it. So is it the problem of theory of group or not?

@xerostomus: not really. I'm not sure what to call it. The study of polynomials and rational functions is so foundational to other parts of mathematics that it doesn't really have a name by itself. Maybe just "algebra." That last paragraph is more like "analysis."
